# MOSS 2007 ItemAdded on Pages library

Tags: sharepoint, events, moss

Is it possible to intercept the ItemAdded event when a new page is created, in MOSS 2007. I've tried to look up the ListTemplateId for the pages library but could not find it. From what I've found, it can only be done on custom lists, image / picture libraries and document libraries.

In theory, the Pages Library is a document library, but it doesn't seem to fire when a new page is created, working off this List type.

Answer (score 0):

What ListTemplateID did you use. It should be 850.

Comment: hi Nitin, how did you find this number? i'm using sharepoint manager, from codeplex but i can't seem to find 850?

Comment: I ran search on the on the physical directory looking for template for Pages Library.